# GUI-displayed timestamps in python program not refreshing?

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, pysimplegui, timestamping

Ok so I've recently written a python-based punchclock program for my company to replace their old paper-and-stamp punchcard system. 
The idea is that everyone has access key cards to get in the doors in the morning, so we're using an RFID reader connected to a Surface Pro just inside the door to clock in with. The reader is programmed so it'll read the card and issue a 'RETURN' event. When it hits, it'll trigger the numbers it just input(`EmpID`) to be run against a SQLite table(`Emps`) that returns the corresponding name(`EmpName`). Then, `EmpName` is used as input to a different table(`Swipes`), along with the `theDate` and `theTime`. The `EmpName` and `theTime` values are also displayed in the text beneath the Input box with an `.Update()` command. 
It.. mostly works. It'll switch names when different cards are run over the reader, but it won't change time. When I check the DB with SQLiteStudio, my entrys have been made, but they all share the same timestamp.
Here's a snip of the frontend code:

```
import pysimplegui as sg
import datetime
import TimeclockBackEnd as be

layout = [[sg.Text('Swipe Your Card')],
          [sg.InputText(size=(6,1), key='IN', focus=True)],
          [sg.Text('', key='theName', size=(45,1))],
          [sg.Text('', key='theTime', size=(45,1))],
          [sg.Button('', key='RETURN', visible=False, bind_return_key=True)],

window = sg.Window('Clock!', layout)
rightNow = datetime.datetime.now()
theTime = rightNow.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
theDate = rightNow.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

while True :
    event, value = window.Read()
    cardNumber = value['IN']
    if event is None:
        break 
    elif event is 'RETURN':
        nameOfSwiper = be.Swipe(cardNumber)
        be.submitToDB(nameOfSwiper, theDate, theTime)
        window['theName'].Update(nameOfSwiper)
        window['theTime'].Update(theTime)
        window['IN'].Update('')
```

and here's the code it calls on in the backend(`be`):

```
def Swipe(EmpID):
    con = sqlite3.connect('Timeclock.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT EmpName FROM Emps WHERE EmpID=?", (EmpID,))
    returnedValue = cur.fetchall()
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    delisted = ''.join(map(str, returnedValue))
    stripped = str(delisted).strip('()')
    strippedAgain = str(stripped).strip(',')
    swiperName = str(strippedAgain).strip("''")
    return swiperName
def submitToDB(EmpName, theDate, theTime):
    con = sqlite3.connect('Timeclock.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Swipes VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (EmpName, theDate, theTime))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Again, it writes to the DB just fine, the only thing I'm having an issue with is how `theTime` doesn't change from the value that was set on its initial swipe. This is the main working parts of the code but if you don't see anything wrong here, feel free to [check my github](https://github.com/zacstrick/PymeClock), I've got the full thing there.
Thanks for helping out!

Comment: You are just initializing the variables `theTime` and `theDate`, you need to add code tode to update these variables.

Comment: The timestamp is set before the "while True" loop.

Comment: @Prudhvi How would I do this?

Comment: @MichaelButscher where would I put this then?

Comment: @zacstrick try adding the declaration of the variables inside while loop.